# Setting busy indicator after button press

Tags: sapui5

I have a simple scenario, a button is pressed and the function onSearchExisting is executed. In the function I open a dialog which contains a table. The data for the table I fetch in the onSearchExisting function. Since the data fetching takes some time, I would like to set the button which triggers this function to busy.
The code looks like this in the function:

```
onSearchExisting : function() {                                                 
    var oButton = this.getView().byId("searchButton");
    oButton.setBusy(true);
    oButton.setBusyIndicatorDelay(0); 

    var oView = this.getView();
    var oDialog = oView.byId("dialog2ID");  
    if (!oDialog) {
        oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(),"xxx.view.fragment.SearchExisting",this);
                                            oView.addDependent(oDialog);
     }

     var oDataModel = new 
     sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/xxxx", true);
     this.getView().byId("tableSearchFrgId").getBinding("items");

     oButton.setBusy(false);    
     oDialog.open();
 },
```

The button is not set to busy, when I press it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding happens asynchronously, so `oButton.setBusy(false);` will get executed immediately after `oButton.setBusy(true);`.

I would suggest you use 'dataReceived' event of the binding and write the `oButton.setBusy(false);` inside the event handler of this event.

Read more here. https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw751abap/helpdata/en/1a/010d3b92c34226a96f202ec27e9217/content.htm

Answer (score 1):

By the time the setBusy(false) statement is executed, only few milliseconds have passed. You should put this statement in a success function of the oData call.

An oData call is async, so next line is immediatly executed even if the data is not retrieved yet.